# How to apply multiple styles in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

I am beginner on WPF and need help.

> Problem:
>   I have 2 Tree View on the form and need to apply 2 different style on pair of 2 Tree View Comparison.

Is there any way we can achieve this ?

I have 2 Tree View look like this

```
<TreeView x:Name="Source1PermissionTreeView" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="630" Width="890" >
<TreeView.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:SharePointUser}">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Source="E:\SWorking\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps.WPF\Images\user.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type entities:SitePermission}">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Source="E:\SWorking\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps.WPF\Images\sitepermission.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type entities:SharePointGroup}">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Source="E:\SWorking\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps.WPF\Images\group.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type entities:SharePointList}">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Source="E:\SWorking\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps.WPF\Images\List.PNG"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type entities:SharePointSite}">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox />
            <Image Source="E:\SWorking\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps\SharePointSecurityApps.WPF\Images\Site.png"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

**How can I apply style in tree view?**

Comment: What are you intending to style, the treeview or treeviewitems or what? If it's literally the treeview then you can define a style for each treeview in that treeview. Or just set properties on the treeview and not use a style at all.

Comment: Thank you @Andy,i want to add style in  treeviewitems only

Comment: OK, so you have treeview1 and treeview2. The hierarchicaldatatemplates you have there in your markup have scope to the treeview they're in. Just cut and paste from one treeview to the other and change the template in copy.